# Unban recalculation of reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, account-suspension

When a user is unbanned from a site, how is their reputation recalculated? Is it just the reputation before they were banned or is it lower?

Comment: It is the reputation they would have had without the suspension. Of course, if they were suspended for voting fraud then there could have been account deletions and vote invalidations involved as well.

Comment: When suspended there is no calculation done. It is simply displayed as **1**. Once unsuspended, reputation is again displayed to be its actual value. During suspension, as Martijn notes, the value may have changed as a result of removed votes, and also as ChrisF notes it may have changed from upvotes or normal interactions as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will be their real reputation including any votes received during the suspension period. This means it could be higher than their pre-suspension reputation. It could be lower than their previous reputation, but that would depend on other actions taken on their account, not the suspension itself.

For example, if the user had been using sock-puppet accounts to inflate their reputation then these accounts (and votes) would have been removed and their reputation will be lower. Note that, however, this removal is independent of the suspension and could have happened without the suspension.

If the user had been suspended for some other reason, then it's less likely to be lower.